# Autogenerate UML from java code

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

I have a Dynamic Web project at Eclipse Galio on linux OS 64 bit and it is my requirement to generate a UML diagram of the classes, interfaces  along with there data members functions and relationships .

I tried various ways and means such as Object Aid and Papyrus , all in vain. The plugins do not get installed.

I also downloaded eclipse-modeling-juno-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64 . However the ecore diagrams herein need to be made from scratch and do not seem to be auto generating from the code present .

Need help .

Comment: Can you tell the what the error message is..............

Comment: i used UML version of eclipse juno , imported the project and auto generated the UML . Its working fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used UML version of eclipse juno , imported the project and auto generated the UML . Its working fine .

Comment: Can you please add a link to the tool/plug-in that you used? Thanks !